# Is there a reference/source paper for the TUCKER_ALS() in Tensor Toolbox for MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, tensor, tensor-decomposition

TUCKER_ALS computes the best rank-(R1,R2,..,Rn) approximation of tensor X, according to the specified dimensions. I am using [MATLAB Tensor Toolbox Version 2.5](http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/TensorToolbox/index-2.5.html). I am wondering if I write a paper, how can I refer to the algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kolda (one of the authors of the MATLAB Tensor Toolbox) also wrote a review paper in SIREV called [Tensor Decompositions and Applications](https://doi.org/10.1137/07070111X) that provides references for algorithms that are at least related. (Without looking at the source, I can't say if they're the same.) You could try looking at Section 4, particularly Section 4.3, for useful references.